# Is perl function dbh->quote still secure?

Tags: sql, perl, escaping

I am currently writing a small script in perl to connect to my db, retrieve some data, and show it to the user. The data retrieved depends of parameters given by the user.

I am using `dbh->quote` to escape the quotes:

```
...
my $dbh=DBI->connect(***);

my $myquery="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE clientName =".$dbh->quote(param('name')) . " AND pass =".$dbh->quote(param('pass'));
my $sth=$dbh->prepare($myquery);
$sth->execute();

my $output=$sth->fetch();
if ($output){
    print @$output;
}
...
```

A friend told me that it might not be secure, and that he read that someone found a vulnerability. I am just beginning with perl, but **I would like to understand what is that vulnerability.**

After some digging I found [this document (pdf)](http://pen-testing.sans.org/resources/papers/gwapt/burp-suiteup-fancy-scanning-mechanisms-125890) that seems to talk about it, but I am not able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: whether it is secure or not, it is silly to use it instead of just `$myquery='SELECT * FROM customers WHERE clientName=? AND pass=?'; ...; $sth->execute( param('name'), param('pass') );`

Comment: @ysth, I heard you want to use quote for performance reasons, because the DB isn't capable of making some optimizations if it doesn't know the type of the parameters in advance. That said, I heard that some DBD actually replace the parameters with quoted values before passing the query to the DB engine rather than passing the provided query and parameters.

Comment: @J.Doe, The only issue I can think of if one of information leak if the query gets logged somewhere. Any insecurities (bugs) in `quote` should be reported immediately, and will be fixed immediately.

Comment: @ikegami the performance thing is almost never an issue for real. It can be with true server-side prepared queries, but e.g. DBD::mysql doesn't use those by default for that reason. In normal situations the performance is the same. Some DBDs do actually just quote in the driver, as you say, and others pass the query to the server as a data structure with SQL and values separate, but the types are known.

Comment: @ikegami however there *is* an issue here, which is with `param`'s list-context behavior and `quote`'s optional second arg. I've explained it in my answer.

Comment: @hobbs, Of course they're known,  but at execute-time, not prepare-time.

Comment: @ikegami yes, but that's my point. Both with quote, and with most DBD's behavior with placeholders, there *is* no advance prepare-time. The server gets the statement and executes it immediately. So it has the full information available to it.

Comment: @hobbs, You didn't say anything about most DBD doing this. And is that true? Does it matter if most do it if the one you use doesn't?

Comment: @ikegami I saw Netanel Rubin cited in the PDF and I knew what it had to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126781/discussion-between-hobbs-and-ikegami).

Comment: @ikegami Quoting should never help performance much, and can hurt depending on the database.  If the database optimizes query plans carefully, then preparing SQL is expensive and quoting hurts you. Oracle is an extreme case.  On the other extreme, MySQL really doesn't care what you do since it doesn't try to do a good job of optimizing query plans.

Comment: @btilly, All my comment points out is that the "common knowledge" that placeholders should always be used isn't always correct. All I know is that tye found that placeholders slowed down his db code. By how much and for what is besides the point, which is that you should check the performance of using placeholders vs avoiding them if performance is a concern for you.

Comment: @ikegami If the performance difference was significant in his case, I would consider it a bug.  In the case of Oracle, the difference has been very large in the past.  Worse yet, the places where it places stress is inside the database, in a way that I've seen actually take the database down.

Comment: Well, the questions and the code look pretty similar to the one of a popular CTF hacking challenge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem mostly doesn't lie with `quote` per se. `quote` is secure if used properly (although it's not the best choice in this situation). However, if `param` is the `param` from CGI.pm, or from anything else that has similar behavior, you have a big problem.

You see, `param` is context-sensitive. In scalar context, if the parameter has a single value (`name=foo`), it returns that value, and if the parameter has multiple values (`name=foo&name=bar`) it returns an arrayref. In *list* context, it returns a list of values, whether there are zero, one, or many. The argument list of a method (such as `quote`) is a list context. That means that someone using your app can cause `quote` to receive *two* values, and `quote`'s optional second argument is an SQL data type that the first argument should be treated as. If the data type is a non-string type like `NUMERIC`, then `quote` will pass its first argument through *without any quoting*. This constitutes an opportunity for SQL injection.

Recommendations:

1. Although `quote` is safe when used properly, placeholders are better, safer, and harder to use wrong. Use DBI placeholders whenever possible, instead of `quote`.
2. Don't use CGI's `param` in argument lists, hash constructors, or any other place where it could return an unexpected number of items and ruin your day. Either put `scalar` out front, assign to a scalar, or assign to an array. Or, better yet, avoid CGI.pm and workalike interfaces entirely.
3. Don't store passwords as plaintext in the database. If anyone ever *does* get access to parts of your database, your users' passwords will be exposed to them. Passwords should be [hashed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) and there are good, easy-to-use Perl modules for doing so ([Authen::Passphrase](https://metacpan.org/pod/Authen::Passphrase) comes to mind).
4. Don't pass passwords as URL parameters. URLs are easily leaked through HTTP referers, browser history, careless copy/paste, etc. Passwords should be POSTed in forms, preferably over a secure connection.

Comment: Ah cool! I think newer versions of `param` warn when you use it in list context to avoid surprises like this

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reach out to [dbi-users mailing list](http://dbi.perl.org/support/) to ask for what vulnerabilities exist. Adding a quote doesn't making things bad as long as you are escaping them. You still make sure you are aware of all [SQL injections attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection). You may also want to avoid passing your password as a url GET parameter (prefer POST requests), since urls (along with any params) are not encrypted and can be easily read.